# How to stack two columns into rows in a single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have following table named **'model'**, I want sql server code to achieve the result.

[image]

My desired output should be as follows,

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this - just another simple way :)

```
SELECT ModelA, Discount
from table1

UNION 

SELECT ModelB, Discount
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `apply` for this purpose:

```
select v.model, t.discount
from t cross apply
     (values (model1), (model2)) v(model);
```

`apply` is a very powerful construct that implements something called "lateral joins".  There are other methods to unpivot such data, but I unpivoting is a good introduction to lateral joins.

Answer (score 0):

It's [`UNION ALL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) that you need:

```
select modela as model, discount from model
union all
select modelb, discount from model
```